# Can't start gwt-2.5 project from intellij idea 2016.3

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, gwt-2.5

When I try to run gwt 2.5 project I get the warning 
"**Language level of 'good-control' module is not supported in current version of GWT. Highest supported level is 1.6
Please reconfigure GWT facet 'GWT'**" in the beginning, after press button **Continue**, intellij idea prepares file and I get an error.

Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51180', transport: 'socket'

Running GPE launcher for GWT-2.5.x version.

Unknown argument: -sourceLevel
Google Web Toolkit 2.5.0
DevMode [-startServer] [-port port-number | "auto"] [-whitelist whitelist-string] [-blacklist blacklist-string] [-logdir directory] [-logLevel level] [-gen dir] [-bindAddress host-name-or-address] [-codeServerPort port-number | "auto"] [-superDevMode] [-server servletContainerLauncher[:args]] [-startupUrl url] [-war dir] [-deploy dir] [-extra dir] [-workDir dir] module[s]

Answer (score 1):

Goto File -> Project structure

Select Project

Change the Project Language Level to 6 or above, depending on the JDK you are using.

[image]